# ABS Pump motor disassembly

Tags: electrical, ford, brakes, abs

I have the strong suspicion that the motor of the ABS Pump is not working anymore in my Ford Transit 2.2L (2008).

So I want to remove the motor and check the carbon brushes. 
As I see it the motor hasn't any direct connection to the break pipes, therefore I can safely remove the motor without need to bleed the ABS system afterwards.

Just wanted to make sure that this assumption is correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you pulse the motor with a scantool? Is the ABS light on? Have you checked for codes? The pump won't activate if a fault code is active in the ABS control module.

Comment: Yes, lights are on (ABS/ESP/Hand brake). But unfortunately I have the strange situation that there are no fault codes. The ABS unit is fully responsive and I can read all sensors such as whees speed, pressure etc., even when performing a on demand self-test on the abs it says test done - everything fine!
When performing the on demand test I'm hearing a slight sound from the solenoid but not from the motor.
I checked connectors, cables, sensors.. so if the problem is within the abs system I guess most probable is a fault of the pump motor.
Besides I'm running out of ideas of possible faults.

Comment: Strange indeed. I don't have any service information for that model so all I can say is, give it a try. At worst you'll have to bleed the brakes. Maybe try a different scan tool as well see if it still won't bring up a code. Also check for TSBs,

Comment: I had the same suspicion that the problem is the scan tool or the adapter,  as the system obviously identifies an abs fault. I tried different scan tools and adapters (all elm-type), no (related) faults. Maybe another adapter would work better. But I think that DTCs are stored centrally, so I cannot imagine why one fault code should hide. When removing unplugging an abs sensors I'm getting plenty of DTCs.
I think I'll remove the motor tomorrow. If this is without result, I really have no idea whats going on..
I will check for TSBs. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Another thought, check to see if the ABS module is actually requesting the light.

Comment: Yeah, I considered this possibility. Actually I don't know, I'm not so experienced in this area. There is a value for "SELTESTDTC" which is the number of stored DTCs which is 0. This is nothing new, as I'm having no DTCs there. But generally it could be an indicator that the lights are set by a module not covered by the diagnose tools I am using. There is also the TCLamp but I don't know if this is the same as ABS/ESP. Actually I would consider it to be a different lamp, but this traction control lamp is set of says the abs unit. 
Do you have any ideas how to check where the lights come from?

Answer (score 1):

TC and ABS work off the same pump, so a pump issue typically lights both warnings.

You may need a Ford specific software capable scan tool to get at the codes.

Also, try your on-demand test again, but also have a friend tap the electric motor lightly with a small hammer. There may be a deadspot. Replacing motor may not be easy, depending on how the shaft connects to the georotor or pump impeller. What I have found during similar situations, is that locating the "motor only" part usually costs as much or more than the entire module. Used (but tested) units are a fraction of the new price.

I forgot to mention - if you have a tool to force a pump test, bleeding the unit after an ABS module exchange is quite easy.  The self test will recirculate the fluid and bring the air to the top vent of the master reservoir.  Some tests allow activation on individual channels (wheels) depending on how the circuits are defined.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. In the meantime the repair light went on, when reading the error codes (I'm using ForScan) I finally got an error code.  ===ABS DTC C1B02:15-2B===
Code: C1B02 - Return Pump
It could be an open circuit, but at least the cable connecting to the control unit has full voltage. So it is probably the motor I guess. I tried to remove the cover, but it is completely stuck - didn't move at all. What do you think about the carbon brushes? (ForScan added the ABS bleeding function for my model recently.) And thanks for the idea with the hammer, I will try it!